# Wordpress Search with post and custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello everyone I am currently building a search function in wordpress I can search for the post type but I am having issues searching for custom fields related to the post type.
Here is the code, I'd rather not using any search plugins or global variables. (unless necessary)

```
class Search {

public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'posts_filter' ) );
}

public function posts_filter( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_search() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'book_writer',
                'value' => get_search_query(),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'book_isbn',
                'value' => get_search_query(),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'book' );
    return $query;
}
}
```

I am not sure how to add these custom fields into the $query, but like this it only returns as a result the post type 'book'(if I pass the correct name) and if I search for the ISBN for example the search doesn't return any results.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you explain how you're submitting the search query?  Are you using the standard WP searchform?

Comment: Hi, if you mean I'm using - get_search_form() - no, I am not, I have created my own form with submit button inside a partial and I have passed it into the homepage.
From the search class I can -  $query->set( 'post_type', 'book' ); - so this bit of code works and It only let me find for 'book' post type and not showing the others...but I also need to query for custom fields related to the post type 'book'.
Btw thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: Your post data isn't passing to this function.  In other words... You're not sending your search string. `get_search_query()` will not work since you have your own form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
class Search {

public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', [ $this, 'posts_filter' ] );
}

public function posts_filter( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_search() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    $meta_query = [
        'relation' => 'OR',
            [ 
                'key' => 'book_writer',
                'value' => $query->query['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'book_isbn',
                'value' => $query->query['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ],
    ];

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'book' );
   }
}
```

From the official documentation, a description of how is the syntax of meta_query
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: No need to `return` anything to `pre_get_posts`. Because the array was passed by reference, any changes to the array elements are applied to the original array outside of the function’s scope.  In other words using `set` is all you need to do

Comment: Really? I've always had problems, when not a fatal error when using the add_filter hook and not returning a value, regardless of what you're saying about the set method being correct

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer...the solution you provided sadly still doesn't work for me , for some reasons I still can't search for any custom fields...also doesn't let me even search for custom post type anymore in my example 'book'

Comment: @Tami - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#parameters `pre_get_posts` is an `action` not a filter, where the parameters `$query` are passed by reference.

Comment: @HowardE you are completely correct, I did not remember this and just assumed it was a filter from the OP original message. Editing the answer to be more correct as per your comment, thank you